# maya python call function from another py file

Tags: python, maya

I have a python script saved to file.

test1.py

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import sys

def process():
    print 'working'
```

I need to run the function from this script inside another python script, inside maya. I have:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('J:\scripts\src\maya')

from test1 import process

test1.process()
```

but it gives me:

```
from test1 import process
# Error: ImportError: file <maya console> line 4: cannot import name process #
```

What am I doing wrong here?

('import test1' gives no error, so the path is correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

Reload your `test1` module, my guess is that you created and imported `test1` without the `process` method inside. To effectively reload a module, you can't just re-import it, you have to use the reload.

```
reload(test1)
from test1 import process
```

---

## Other observations:

**Use raw string when using paths:**

Add `r` before your path string:
`sys.path.append(r'J:\scripts\src\maya')`

[Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

> The backslash () character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character. String literals may optionally be prefixed
>   with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use
>   different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.

**Check the way you import your modules:**

You wrote, which is not valid:

```
from test1 import process
test1.process()
```

But you can have either way:

```
import test1 
test1.process()
```

or:

```
from test1 import process
process()
```

To sum-up these are the ways to import a module or package:

```
>>> import test_imports
>>> from test_imports import top_package
>>> from test_imports import top_module
test_imports.top_module
>>> from test_imports.top_package import sub_module
test_imports.top_package.sub_module
```

assuming you have the following hierarchy:

```
J:\scripts\src\maya # <-- you are here
.
`-- test_imports
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- top_package
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- sub_package
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   `-- other_module.py
    |   |-- sub_module.py
    `-- top_module.py
```

Credits goes to [Sam & Max blog](http://sametmax.com/les-imports-en-python/) (French)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the script location path in system path.

and if you are making this as a python package than do not forget to add
a `__init__.py` file in the package directory.

Than you can execute following code.

```
import sys
path = r'J:\scripts\src\maya'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

import test1
test1.process()
```